# Getting full stats of auto scaled system on Amazon

Tags: autoscaling, amazon-cloudwatch

I was wondering how **Statistics Aggregated by Auto Scaling Group** feature on CloudWatch works. Does it aggregate all stats of all instances ever spawned in certain time range and calculate average of every metric (i.e. CPU usage and etc...)?

Does it retain stats of instances that were automatically spawned and later killed?

Thanks